# How does the ‘doubleb’ command in Stata estimate WTP?

Tags: stata

I am seeking clarity on how the `doubleb` command in Stata estimates WTP. According to Lopez-Feldman (2012), the command ‘directly’ calculates the coefficients to do so ([see attached picture from the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IJQv.png)). However, this text does not clarify what ‘directly’ means, so I am unsure what is happening and how to calculate this manually.

If anyone can shed any light on what’s going on under the hood here, I would really appreciate it!

Reference: Lopez-Feldman, A. 2012, ‘Introduction to contingent valuation using Stata’, Economic Research and Teaching Centre, Paper No. 41018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of `doubleb` is rather short so I'll give it a try:

The ado-file for the command ([doubleb.ado](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/d/doubleb.ado)) does a simple check then calls a maximum-likelihood solver for the likelihood function `doubleb_ll` which is defined in [doubleb_ll.ado](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/d/doubleb_ll.ado). I would say that this is the implementation of equation (8) on page 12 on the paper you linked.